# Examples of warped product manifolds?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, spacetime

Bishop and O'Neil defined [warped product manifolds](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=warped+product+manifolds). Space-times are good examples of such warped product manifolds. Is there a famous and important example of space-times $I×M$ where $M$ is itself a warped product manifold? One can construct many such examples, but I want an example from physics where the fiber of the space-times is a warped product manifold?

Kindly refer to the importance of the example in brief. A good reference is fine and enough.